# How do I train?

Tags: pokemon-go

One of the achievements in Pokemon Go states I need to 'Train *X* times' in order to unlock it:

[image: Pokemon Go]

I haven't yet reached level 5, so I'm not sure if it refers to having a gym battle (which would be weird since I haven't seen a gym battle referred to as 'training' yet.)

How do I carry out training?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this means participating in gym battles with your own team. Not certain though.

Comment: From what I understand, you need to train at a gym, but gym's only unlock at lv5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can train at allied gyms that are in the same team as you are.

Answer (score 1):

While this is a very old question, the current answer has since been outdated as training to build up the "Ace Trainer" medal changed in late 2018.

---

When the gym system was reworked in mid-2017, the "Ace Trainer" medal was no longer available as you could no longer train in gyms. This was this case until late 2018, when the battle system was implemented. Now, can train by battling against the team leaders in trainer battles.

To begin these battles, tap the "nearby" bar on the bottom right of the screen, and swipe left to choose which leaders you want to battle. Each leader has different Pokemon based on the league you choose. If you win the battle, then your ace medal will increase.

**Blanche** (Mystic)

- Great League: Magikarp, Feebas, and Squirtle
- Ultra League: Alolan Ninetales, Glalie, & Lapras
- Master League: Lapras, Gliscor, & Articuno

**Candela** (Valor)

- Great League: Slugma, Vulpix, and Charmander
- Ultra League: Alolan Marowak, Houndoom, & Infernape
- Master League: Infernape, Electivire, & Moltres

**Spark** (Instinct)

- Great League: Magnemite, Mareep, and Pikachu
- Ultra League: Alolan Raichu, Magneton, & Manectric
- Master League: Manectric, Milotic, & Zapdos

Comment: I feel like ultra and great are the wrong way around here

Comment: @Pyritie You're right. Copy/pasting typos got the best of me